# php + xvfb + flashplayer

Tags: php, flash, shell-exec, xvfb

I'm using php to launch xvfb with flashplayer:

```
<?php

shell_exec("xvfb-run /home/myuser/flashplayerdebugger /home/myuser/animations/2016-01-30/Animation.swf");

?>
```

From terminal it successfully executes. But from browser there is no reaction. Other commands work with shell_exec from web. But not xvfb with flashplayer.

Comment: Could be a permission issue. When you're running the script in terminal, are you running it as the web server or your user?

Comment: With my user. But apache2 does give a permission for ffmpeg. Is there difference with xvfb-run?

Comment: Is shell_exec allowed in php.ini?

Comment: Of course. shell_exec("ffmpeg ...") allways works fine.

Comment: what about trying to run the command as apache? su www-data and then run xfvb ... (If www-data is the appropriate user)